# My python script closes as soon as I interact with it

Tags: python, playsound

When I launch the script and press the "]" the script closes. And I know that it works because I tried it in IDLE and it works fine and the music is playing as intended.

```
import keyboard
from playsound import playsound

while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(']'):
                sound = playsound(r'C:\Users\jaros\Downloads\DoomMusic.mp3')
```

I tried using "time.sleep()" and "Input()" but nothing worked. The script just keeps closing whenever I press the "]" key.

Comment: This is an infinite loop.  I don't see how it would ever exit.

Comment: Maybe you could try opening the script through the terminal (as opposed to just double-clicking it, if that's what you were doing): that way if it crashes, you'd be able to see the error message left behind, if there is one.

Comment: Could it be that you have several installations of Python on your machine?

Comment: Did you get any error/msg after pressing `]`?

Comment: try to add the whole code inside a try block and catch an error using `except Exception as e` and print e.  [Code](https://codeshare.io/ZJ1J77). Double-click and tell me what msg you get?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

To use the "keyboard" package properly, do it like this:

```py
import keyboard
from playsound import playsound

while True:
    keyboard.wait("]")
    playsound(r"C:\Users\jaros\Downloads\DoomMusic.mp3")
```

## Rationale

Both of the packages you reference (keyboard and playsound) seem to be third-party and not part of the standard library.

### Playsound Is Old

Please be advised that the [playsound](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound) package seems old and broken; the release on PyPI is from March 2020 and needs to be updated by the package maintainers. Pip version 22.3.1 prints a deprecation warning on installation:

> DEPRECATION: playsound is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559

The "playsound" module seems also seems to be broken on Windows, but working on macOS. On Windows 10 I am not able to make it work. I get horrible error messages of the type:

```
>>> playsound(r"C:\Users\traal\Downloads\Garry Schyman - Praan.mp3")

    Error 277 for command:
        open "C:\Users\traal\AppData\Local\Temp\PS0vt8vkrq.mp3"
    A problem occurred in initializing MCI.
```

The source code for playsound states that it was [tested on Windows 7 and Python 2.7](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/9cf4af20caa5ae8586f88b65659681b24f0c4e69/playsound.py#L22) -- these are super old versions.

I would recommend looking for a different package than playsound, unless the package maintainers release an updated version soon.

### Proper Use of the Keyboard Package

I googled the [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) package, and it seems that the way you're using it is an anti-pattern. [According to the documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#repeatedly-waiting-for-a-key-press):

```py
import keyboard

# Don't do this!
#
#while True:
#    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
#        print('space was pressed!')
#
# This will use 100% of your CPU and print the message many times.

# Do this instead
while True:
    keyboard.wait('space')
    print('space was pressed! Waiting on it again...')

# or this
keyboard.add_hotkey('space', lambda: print('space was pressed!'))
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: @codester_09 traal's answer addresses the issue of OP's sudden exit from their program. Maybe it was not made clear, but maybe the 100% CPU usage from OP's "anti-pattern" code forced an exit on the program...

Comment: @poiboi OP says code work in IDE. I don't think this is because of CPU usage.